# Django - Is there a way to validate a model with its related models before transaction commit?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

Suppose I have two related models (my case is a bit more complicate, but the idea is same):

```py
class Main(models.Model):
    amount: int = models.IntegerField()

class Child(models.Model):
    main: Main = models.ForeignKey(Main, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount: int = models.IntegerField()
```

Whenever creating or changing a `Main` instance, I want to make sure that it is 'valid'. In my case, a valid `Main` object means that the sum of all of its children amounts is equal to its own amount:

```py
def validate_main(main: Main) -> bool:
    children = Child.objects.filter(main=main)
    return sum(child.amount for child in children) == main.amount
```

If I'm right, this creates a deadlock:

- I can't call `validate_main` **before** saving `Main`, because then I wouldn't be able to create and save the related `Child` instances (because `Main` won't have `pk`), so this check will fail.
- I can't call `validate_main` **after** saving `Main`, because this will enable a situation where there is an invalid state in the database (someone can create a `Main` without ever creating its children).

I thought about validating the changes in the database just before every transaction commit, by this allowing to create both `Main` and its children in the same `transaction.atomic` context, but it seems Django doesn't have that kind of signal integration.

Comment: If that particular `main` instance isn't in the database yet, then how can there be any `child` instances that reference it? So the only way this validity check makes sense is if you are creating a set of children at the same time as the Main - in which case surely you can just check the validity in code right then, before committing anything to the database?

Comment: What does it mean "in the same time"? That's exactly what I want to achieve, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: presumably you have a view function (that likely corresponds to the POST of some form) that handles the creation of all these objects at once. So can't you create the necessary objects, do the validity check on those values, and then, only if the check passes, save everything to the database. By "at the same time" I basically mean "as part of the same request".

Comment: This is the point - I want to make this validation at database level, not on each request. I want to validate that programmers that use my code use it as intended, and are not creating illegal state in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use django signal to validate the values before entering the `main` model. If they are valid then continue with saving the record & If the values are not valid then raise an error or return the boolean value you were returning in `validate_main` function to stop django from saving them.

see below code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Main(models.Model):
    amount = models.IntegerField()

class Child(models.Model):
    main = models.ForeignKey(Main, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField()

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Main)
def validate_main(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    children = Child.objects.filter(main=instance.id)
    return sum(child.amount for child in children) == instance.amount
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: As I wrote, this is not possible: for that to work, before calling `Main.save()` I'll need to first save its `Child` models. The child models can't be saved before saving the main, because then main won't have pk yet:
```m = Main(amount=10)
c = Child(amount=10, main=m)
c.save()```
Raises `ValidationError`